# Js: Why shift and not push?

Tags: javascript, push

I want to do a simple countdown function, that, if I'm passing 10 as an argument, should return an array like [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

I thought that each time my argument "n" was passing in this recursive function below, I would have had just to push the new value "n" in an array. But it looks like the push method is not appropriate here and it needs the unshift method, as shown below.

But why? I don't get the logic.

Below: function pushing the n:

```
function countdown(n){
  if (n < 1) {
    return []
  } 
  let array = []
  array = countdown(n-1)
  array.push(n)
  return array
}

console.log(countdown(10))
```

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

Below, function unshifting the n:

```
function countdown(n){
  if (n < 1) {
    return []
  } 
  let array = []
  array = countdown(n-1)
  array.unshift(n)
  return array
}

console.log(countdown(10))
```

[ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]

Comment: With `push()`, your result is `[countdown(9), 10]`, which is `[countdown(8), 9, 10]`, which is `[countdown(7), 8, 9, 10]`, which is… Does that help you?

Comment: Standard recursive question, asked and answered hundreds of times...

Comment: Notice you're `push`ing *after* the recursive call happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.push()` adds elements to the end of the array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

With your `Array.push()` implementation of `countdown()`, the recursive function first computes all the smaller array elements (`array = countdown(n-1`). Then, after the recursive call, the `push` adds `n` to the array. So for `countdown(2)` the array is:

```
countdown(1).push(2)
```

and since `countdown(1)` is `countdown(0).push(1)`, and `countdown(0)` is `[]`, we can expand this to

```
[].push(1).push(2)
```

which ends up looking like

```
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
```

so we can see that the `push` implementation appends successively larger values to the end of the array.

[`Array.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), on the other hand, adds elements to the beginning of the array. So, following the same recursive "expansion" as before, the `unshift` implementation adds successively larger values to the front of the array. `countdown(2)` becomes `countdown(1).unshift(2)` which is basically the same as `[2].push(countdown(1)`. So the output goes through the steps

```
[]
[1]
[2, 1]
```

Comment: Ok here was the point: so all the recursive stuff will go on (as I'm calling my function count-down() before the return. So if I'm passing 5 it will stock, somehow: 5,4,3,2,1, then it will be pushed in the array, starting from the last result, so: 1,2,3,4,5. If i use the unshift method it will be: 1 then 2,1  then 3,2,1 etc... Is it ok if I'm simplifying thist like this or it sounds weird ? (thanks a lot anyway)

Comment: "all the recursive stuff will go on (as I'm calling my function count-down() before the return" yes, exactly. Other than async function calls, which aren't happening here, code in a function is executed top-to-bottom.

Comment: I'm going to read also about " hoisting".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is easier to simplifiy the recursive function to show that if more values are needed, it returns an array with the actual value and a spreaded rest array.

To get an array with descending order, you need to take the larget value to the left sinde and the rest to the right side. That means `push` is wrong and `unshift` is right.

```js
function countdown(n) {
    if (n < 1) return []
    return [n, ...countdown(n - 1)];
}

console.log(countdown(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of `push` as the push operation of a stack that goes from left to right. In that context it makes sense that it will simply push an element onto the top of the stack (the top here is the rightmost element)

`unshift` is like the enqueue function in a queue that goes from left to right. This will add an element to the end of the queue (leftmost side) and the start of the queue will be pushed further a bit (to the right).